# Queries on the concept of a closed subspace

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Section 2.12 of David Luenberger's "Optimization by Vector Space Methods" contains two theorems as follows.

> Theorem 1. In a Banach space a subset is complete if and only if it is closed.

> Theorem 2. In a normed linear space, any finite-dimensional subspace is complete.

I am also aware of the following, widely-known consequence of the above two theorems:

> Corollary. Every finite-dimensional subspace in a Banach space (and therefore a Hilbert space) is complete and closed.

I have the following queries on my mind while trying to absorb this corollary.

> Query A. Given that every metric space is a closed subset of itself, can it be asserted that "each subspace $\mathcal M$ in a normed vector space is closed in $\mathcal M$ (the ambient space), irrespective of the dimension of $\mathcal M$"?

> Query B. Isn't "the 1-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathbb R^1$ not closed in the 2-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathbb R^2$ (the ambient space)"? If it is not closed, does this situation not serve as a counterexample to the above-cited corollary?

> Query C. Is there an example of a subspace $\mathcal M$ in a normed vector space $\mathcal V$ such that $\mathcal M$ closed in $\mathcal V$ (the ambient space) and such that $\mathcal M$ is a proper subset of $\mathcal V$?

My queries assume the following definition of a closed subset: A subset $\mathcal S$ in an ambient metric space $\mathcal X$ is said to be closed in $\mathcal X$, if, for each point $x$ in $\mathcal X$, we have $$x \text{ is a limit point of }\mathcal S⟹ x \text{ is in } \mathcal S.$$

I have tried to find answers to these queries by reading previous posts discussing similar questions and related examples. However, I wasn't successful, and would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a  topological space you can talk about a subset being closed in $X$ but just saying that a set is closed without specifying the ambient space does not make sense. (However, very often the ambient space is understood).

What makes you think that a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^{2}$ is not closed in $\mathbb R^{2}$? All finite dimensional subspaces of a normed linear space $X$ are closed **in $X$**. The fact that a space is closed in itself has no relevance in these results.

Proof of the fact that $\mathbb R^{1}$  is closed in $\mathbb R^{2}$: Supoose $x,y) $ is a limit point of $\mathbb R^{1}$.  If this is not in $\mathbb R^{1}$ then $y \neq 0$. Consider the open ball of radius $|y|$ around $(x,y)$. If $(u,v)$ is in this ball then $|y-v| <|y|$. This implies that $v \neq 0$. Thus there is a neighborhood of $(x,y)$ which contains no point of $\mathbb R^{2}$, contradicting the fact that $(x,y)$ is  a limit point.

Comment: I see that many limit points of $\mathbb R^1$ are in $\mathbb R^2$ but not in $\mathbb R^1$. That makes me deduce that $\mathbb R^1$ is not closed in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Can yuo give me such a limit point?

Comment: I am not able to pinpoint a limit point numerically. However, the following definition from Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (Third Edition) makes me think that there are many such limit points.

Comment: 2.18 Definition. Let $X$ be a metric space. All points and sets mentioned below are understood to be elements and subsets of $X$. 

(a) Skipping this part which has the definition of a neighborhood.

(b) A point $p$ is a limit point of the set $E$ if every neighborhood of $p$ contains a point $q \neq p$ such that $q \in E$.

Comment: If $(x,y)$ is a limit point of $(x_n,0)$ then there is a subsequence converging to $(x,y)$. This implies that $y=0$.  So $\mathbb R^{1}$ is closed in $\mathbb R^{2}$.

Comment: @RajPanse I have given a detailed proof.

Comment: Got it. I think my questions arose due to my lack of understanding of what a limit point is. Thanks for exhaustively clarifying.